# Timeshift keeps including a folder which is in the exclude list

Tags: 22.04, rsync, timeshift

I'm using Timeshift and I have included my home folder but excluded a particular sub folder.

I have rm- rf'd the Timeshift folder on my second drive.

However, every time I click Create, Timeshift copies the excluded sub-folder.

What am I missing?

UPDATE

Okay so it seems the include/exclude filtering really matters:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=325584